# JavaScript Object storage and usage via sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects, session-storage

```
var obj = { 
conn : null,
first : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var myObj = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({ 
        url : some value,
        // other parameters
        success : function() {
            myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
            sessionStorage.setItem('connection', JSON.stringify(myObj.conn));
        }
    });
   },
second : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var myObj = this;
    var conntn = sessionStorage.getItem('connection');
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax ({ 
            url : some value,
            // other parameters
            success : function() { 
                var parsedConnection = JSON.parse(conntn);
                parsedConnection.sendMsg(data.id, data.nid);
            }
        });
}
};
var Connection = (function() {
    function Connection(uid, url) {
       this.uid = uid;
       this.open = false;
       this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://"+url);
       this.setupConnectionEvents();
    },
    sendMsg : function(id, nid) {
        alert("Working");
    },
    // other functions
})();
```

Now basically an object is assigned to conn variable in AJAX callback function of first function and I am storing the object via `sessionStorage` and retrieving the object in the second function and using it in the AJAX callback but when I call the method via `parsedConnection.sendMsg(data.id, data.nid);` it is throwing an error that

> TypeError: parsedConnection.sendMsg is not a function

I did use `console.log(parsedConnection);` and it shows that object is there with proper values. I just want to know how to retrieve the object and call the method on it in AJAX callback function of second. Thanks!

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format can only store **plain objects**. No prototype-based objects allowed.

Comment: @hindmost Any suggested changes then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store javascript in a Local Storage Object and run it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313770/can-i-store-javascript-in-a-local-storage-object-and-run-it)

Comment: @hindmost Sorry but I don't understand how `eval` function will help here?

Comment: `eval` (as well as `script` element) is ultimately the **only way** to run dynamically built JS code which is exactly your case (what you want).

Comment: @hindmost Can you please make change(s) to the above mention code if possible for better clarity as I am not getting where exactly to make the change. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have no intention to do your work for you. Read the related question thoroughly, it has enough information to get started. (tip: pay attention to the 2nd rated answer if you need certain code example)

Comment: @hindmost I am not still not getting it (I don't know why) but I will try to figure it out. Thanks anyway!