# Storing within localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm using the following code to enable and disable a stylesheet on a site (for user accessibility, applies to entire sites colour scheme)

```
$(function() {
      var accessStyle;
      $(".css_switch").click(function() {
        if (!accessStyle) {
          accessStyle = $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/accessibility.css" />').appendTo(document.head)[0];
        }
        else if (accessStyle.sheet) {
          accessStyle.sheet.disabled = !accessStyle.sheet.disabled;
        }
      });
    });
```

I am wondering what the correct code to store this (possibly within localStorage?) so once the user clicks on the .css_switch button once, it remains in place across the entire site until the click it again to turn it off.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store javascript in a Local Storage Object and run it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313770/can-i-store-javascript-in-a-local-storage-object-and-run-it)

Comment: Have you tried reading any docs on localstorage?

Comment: Do you want the change to persist even if the user navigates away from your page and eventually comes back, or just for the current session? If you want it to persist, you could use local storage or a cookie. Otherwise storing as a js variable might work, depending on how your site is implemented (such as a SPA).